# Symfony2 Container Aware Form Type

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Is there a way to make a form type container aware?

As an example I have 3 entities Account, User and Event. Users have ManyToMany relationship in order to associate many users with many other users (called approvers), reason for this is so that an Event created by a User can have a list of Users who area able approve it. In the User edit form where I have an approvers multiple select field the list needs to be filtered by Account so I need my form type to be container aware in order to filter the list of available Users by Account ID.

Am I right in thinking that making the form type container aware is the right way to go? I'd like to use the entity manager to filter a list of Users by Account.

Comment: So why would you make it container aware? Inject entity manager or UserManager or whatever you have into it and use it to filter list.

Comment: Not necessarily container aware, I'm new to Symfony just getting my head around how it all works. So I can define a service and inject the entity manager?

Comment: You can even inject container itself, but I didn't tell you that in case someone asked, ok? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>1</kbd> Inject the entity manager through the constructor

```
<?php

namespace Acme\YourBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class YourType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * The entity manager
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       //build your form here



    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'name_of_your_form';
    }

}
```

<kbd>2</kbd> Declare it as a service

```
services:
    # Form type
    acme_your_bundle.name_of_your_form.form.type:
        class: Acme\YourBundle\Form\Type\YourType
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

---

### Note:

If you're starting with Symfony, take this advice:

look very closely at the code of the [FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle), it will give you exactly what you need to do anything in symfony, from form models, to form factories, to the creation of special services (like composer, authorizer, etc..). The more you study this bundle, the quicker you will learn symfony, I guarantee you that 100%. Finally, in your specific case, look at the [FormFactory in this bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/tree/master/FormFactory)

Comment: Ok then do I need to use $this->container->get() when creating the form instead of instantiating the Type class directly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A good practice is generally to create a form factory and inject the form type directly in the form factory. You would then declare your form factory as a service and use it in your controller to create the form `$this->container->get('your_form_factory')->create()`

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick tip that might help you learn very very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

This solution allows you to inject the container into many forms without each of your form types being a service:

Create a new form type:

```
class ContainerAwareType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'container' => $this->container
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'container_aware';
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

Declare as a service:

```
services:
    app.container_aware_type:
        class: Burgerfuel\CmsBundle\Form\Type\ContainerAwareType
        calls:
          - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: 'container_aware' }
```

This type is now available to be a 'parent' to any other form type - whether its a service or not. In this case the important part is that `setDefaultOptions` from this class will be used to help build the `$options` argument that will be passed into any 'child' form types.

In any of your form types you can do this:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent() {
        return 'container_aware';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $container = $options['container'];
        $builder->add( ...
```

This solution will be beneficial if you can't make your form type a service for some reason.
Or it can save you time if you are creating many types that require access to the container.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way to do this**, without doing any dependency injection / declaring a service.

In your FormType file, **force the form to require an EntityManager**

```
//..    
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    //...
    //...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired('entity_manager');
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('entity_manager', EntityManager::class);
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to (and forced - important for testing), **pass the entity manager from the controller.**

```
public function yourControllerAction(Request $request)
{
    //..
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm('Acme\YourBundle\Form\YourEntityType', $yourEntityObject, array(
                'entity_manager'=>$em,
            )); 
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    //..
}
```