# symfony 2, list of users

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I try to do a select with all my users. An admin has is his part a possibility to change the infos from the users. Email adress for example.

I need to do a select with all the users, Then the admin choice a user and then he can change his infos.

How can I do that?

Thanks
Best regards

I tried to do so:

```
<?php
 
namespace gestEntrSym\gestBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 
class entrainementGroupeForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
 
       $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();
        $builder
            ->add('date');
    }
 
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'entrainementGroupe';
    }
}
```

Then I have this error:

Attempted to call method "get" on class "gestEntrSym\gestBundle\Form\entrainementGroupeForm" in C:\Users\ale252\Dropbox\wamp\www\gestEntrSym\src\gestEntrSym\gestBundle\Form\entrainementGroupeForm.php line 12. Did you mean to call: "getName", "getParent"?

My idea is to take the users array to do a foreach and do a $builder->add('date') for all the values of the array.

This is just a try with a date type, then I can do the same with a choice type.

---

I have done anything like that:

```
<?php
 
namespace gestEntrSym\gestBundle\Form;
 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use gestEntrSym\UserBundle\Entity\User;
 
class entrainementGroupeForm extends AbstractType {
 
    /**
     * The entity manager
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $users;
 
    /**
     * @param EntityManager
     */
    public function __construct($users) {
        $this->users = $users;
    }
 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
 
 
        foreach ($this->users as $value) {
//            var_dump($value);
//            exit;
            $builder->add('public', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => $value->getNom(),
                'required' => false,
            ));
        }
    }
 
    public function getName() {
        return 'entrainementGroupe';
    }
 
}
```

Then in my controller:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();
 
        $entrainementGroupe = new entrainementGroupe();
//        var_dump($users[0]);
//        exit;
        $form = $this->createForm(new entrainementGroupeForm($users), $entrainementGroupe);
```

But I have always an error:

Neither the property "public" nor one of the methods "getPublic()", "public()", "isPublic()", "hasPublic()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "gestEntrSym\gestBundle\Entity\entrainementGroupe".

Somebody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: $this->get works if you are in a Controller, but now you parent is an AbstractType.. $this->get function not exists

Comment: Inject entity manager or container into the form class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047431/symfony2-container-aware-form-type

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a form with all the users (100) and for each a date - this wouldn't be convenient, so if you want to modify just one user's info, you can use the same "load all users" from the "Basic usage" and on user select from the dropdown you load the user data in the fields ( date, id,name and so on) , modify the required ones, click save and when clicking save in the controller/model you will get the user you have "choosen" and the data for it

here is how you can select all users from the database very easy [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html),

here is the link to read how to "listen to the select option and load the data dynamically" in the forn [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)